# Periodically update FigureCanvasKivyAgg object

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, kivy

I'm quite new to Kivy and I want to have an app updating a graph periodically, ie: every minute.

Using the following example:

```
<mainScreen>
    RewardGraph:

from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class RewardGraph(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(plt.gcf(), **kwargs)

class AppLayout(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.PlotRewardGraph(rArray), 60)
        return mainScreen()

    def PlotRewardGraph(self, rArray):
        plt.cla()
        plt.plot(rArray, color='r')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.gcf()

class mainScreen(GridLayout):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AppLayout().run()
```

Say my `rArray` updates every minute and I want to plot it out. The app only shows the graph once at its starting value and stays there. For example, if the `rArray` is [0, -1], then the screen would show this:

[image]

Is there a way I could update the graph? I tried using but `plt.cla()` `plt.clf()` but nothing changes.

If the rArray increases to say [0, -1, 0.5], the graph stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an `id` to your `RewardGraph` in your `kv`, you can use that to access the `RewardGraph` for updates:

```
<mainScreen>
    cols: 1
    RewardGraph:
        id: graph
```

Then your `PlotRewardGraph()` method can update the `RewardGraph`:

```
def PlotRewardGraph(self, rArray):
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(rArray, color='r')
    plt.grid(True)
    graph = self.root.ids.graph
    graph.figure = plt.gcf()
    graph.draw()
```